# using reduce to left join dataframes which names get from ls()

Tags: r, list, left-join, reduce, mget

Using `reduce` and `left_join` to combine `table_base` `table_a` `table_b`.
Method A can work,but have to input object names , it's little boring.
Method B can get object names but can't return correct result ,how to fix it ?Thanks！

```
library(tidyverse)
table_base <- data.frame(cat=c("a","b","c","d"))

table_a <- data.frame(cat=c("a","b"),
                      value=c(1,2))

table_b <- data.frame(cat=c("a","c","d"),
                      value=c(7,9,10))

# method A: ok, but have to input object name one by one in list

reduce(list(table_base,table_a,table_b),left_join,by='cat') 



# method B: can't work
reduce(list(mget(ls(pattern="^table"))),left_join,by='cat')
```

Comment: `mget` already outputs a list, so `reduce(mget(ls(pattern="^table")),left_join,by='cat')` works... note that the list has a different order than `list(table_base,table_a,table_b)`, so the output of the `left_join()` also differs,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues you need to address

1. `mget` returns a list already, so you don't need `list()` to wrap `mget` any more
2. The order of dataframes in the list matters, if you want to achieve the same result, you need to adjust the order of dataframes for iterative `left_join`

## Code (Example only)

```
> reduce(mget(ls(pattern = "^table")[c(3, 1, 2)]), left_join, by = "cat")
  cat value.x value.y
1   a       1       7
2   b       2      NA
3   c      NA       9
4   d      NA      10
```

Comment: Once you hard-code the order of the tables you might as well hard-code the table names directly, which obviates the need for the detour via `ls()` and `mget()`, and makes the code drastically more readable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, that's true and I agree. I hereby just want to point out the issues that prevents OP achieving the desired output. OP can decide how to proceed according to own cases.